# Button not responding to OnClickListener()

Tags: android, button

So I create a custom dialog where I set it to an xml file. In that file I have 2 buttons. One of them is responding to it's onClick counterpart where the other one isn't. I have NO idea why it isn't. I've set it's ID correctly, and done everything exactly the same way I did the other button... it's not giving me any errors, it's just not doing ANYTHING. 
I even set the button attribute "clickable" to true... I'm out of ideas.

Furthermore, it seems that if I try to add another button it also is unresponsive when clicked... is there some limit to the amount of widgets a dialog can take? lol...

it's the SaveAndFinish button that isn't working

```
Dialog createFlashCards = new Dialog(FlashCard.this);
                                createFlashCards.setContentView(R.layout.flash_card_create);
                                final EditText Question = (EditText)createFlashCards.findViewById(R.id.FlashCard_CreateQuestionEditText);
                                final EditText Answer = (EditText)createFlashCards.findViewById(R.id.FlashCard_CreateAnswerEditText);
                                Button SaveFlashCard = (Button)createFlashCards.findViewById(R.id.create_new_saved_FlashCard);
                                Button FinishAndSave = (Button)createFlashCards.findViewById(R.id.finish_creating_flashCards);

                                //saves the flashCard to the file on their phone
                                SaveFlashCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                        //have to check for empty questions or answers
                                        if (!Question.getText().toString().equals("") && !Answer.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                                String newLineQuestionFixer = Question.getText().toString();
                                                String newLineAnswerFixer = Answer.getText().toString();
                                                newLineQuestionFixer = newLineQuestionFixer.replaceAll("\n", "<GAR>");
                                                newLineAnswerFixer = newLineAnswerFixer.replaceAll("\n", "<GAR>");
                                                Statics.addDataIntoFlashCardFile(FlashCard.this, input.getText().toString(), newLineQuestionFixer,
                                                        newLineAnswerFixer, Statics.mainPageListPosition);
                                            Toast.makeText(FlashCard.this, "FlashCard successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(FlashCard.this, "Must have a question and an answer to save a flashCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        Question.setText("");
                                        Answer.setText("");
                                    }
                                });

                                FinishAndSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                        //have to check for empty questions or answers
                                        if (!Question.getText().toString().equals("") && !Answer.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                                String newLineQuestionFixer = Question.getText().toString();
                                                String newLineAnswerFixer = Answer.getText().toString();
                                                newLineQuestionFixer = newLineQuestionFixer.replaceAll("\n", "<GAR>");
                                                newLineAnswerFixer = newLineAnswerFixer.replaceAll("\n", "<GAR>");
                                                Statics.addDataIntoFlashCardFile(FlashCard.this, input.getText().toString(), newLineQuestionFixer,
                                                        newLineAnswerFixer, Statics.mainPageListPosition);
                                            Toast.makeText(FlashCard.this, "FlashCard successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        //just an intent to refresh the class
                                        Intent refresh = new Intent(FlashCard.this, FlashCard.class);
                                        refresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                        startActivity(refresh);
                                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(FlashCard.this, "Must have a question and an answer to save a flashCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                createFlashCards.show();
```

here is the declaration of the buttons in xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/finish_creating_flashCards"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_round_xml"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Finish and Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_new_saved_FlashCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_round_xml"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Save_FlashCard"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: Have you used the debug tool to see if you are entering at least the onClick() function?

Comment: I have, and I'm not... that's what's puzzling to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to catch click event like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/finish_creating_flashCards"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_round_xml"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Finish and Save"
    android:onClick="finishCreatingFlashCards" />
```

In your .java code file:

```
public void finishCreatingFlashCards(View v) {
        // your code on button click.
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is you're basically just making a function call and I need certain variables from the alertDialog above this one that I can't get unless they're within the dialog.

Comment: Then why don't you use positive and negative buttons?

Comment: I just figured it out..it was because I have 2 ways of accessing this menu, and I was accessing it from one I forgot about where it doesn't have the above onClickListener().. It's a 1000 line file so it took me a while to find it >.<
Thank you for your help!

Also thanks to you, I learned you can call functions from xml pretty cool!